# Query templating in Grafana with Elasticsearch datasource

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, grafana-templating

I have the values like Name:"Christopher; Johnson" , "Christopher; Nolan" etc. with the firstname and lastname seperated by a semicolon from the ES datasource. I'm trying to get these names in the variable template in Grafana.

The query I tried:

```
{"find":"terms", "field":"Name", "query":"Name:*Christopher*"}
```

and the error I got is "Only word and digit characters are allowed in variable names". Doing 
`{"find":"terms", "field":"Name", "query":"Name:*Christopher* AND NOT Name:*;*"}` will filter out all the names having ";"

Is there a way to get all these variables in a query template like:

- Christopher
- Johnson
- Nolan

irrespective of whether it is a firstname or a lastname.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the query as `{"find":"terms", "field":"Name"}`
and then use the regex field below the query field to filter the names for the names you are looking for.

To find Christopher you could do something like `/.*[Christopher].*/`

Here is an example of a query that finds only clientCDIRs that have A2 in them: 
[image]

Comment: Do you need those square brackets? It worked for me without them

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a bit late but for anyone else hitting this issue, it's referring to the variable name set. Not the variables that are returned from a query.

[image: Name cannot contain a space]